# Understanding F-Bound polymorphism in Java

Tags: java, f-bounded-polymorphism

I learned how generics and wildcards works, but I'm having a hard time understanding the concept of F-Bound polymorphism and how to use it in the Java language.

For example, if I understood it well, given the default method compareTo(T o) of comparable, to have a different behaviour of the method based on what T actually is, instead of doing something like: if T is int do this, else if T is String do that in the method body, which can't be done, a new class that extends comparable having newclass as type parameter must be created and then inside the new class an override of compareTo(newclass o) must be createad, and the same must be done everytime a new behaviour of the method is needed. Is this correct?

I'm looking for some other simple example in practice that can help me  better understand this concept and when/how to use it.

Comment: *"everytime a new behaviour of the method is needed"* This is putting the cart before the horse; you write a new class when you *need* a new class, and you implement the `compareTo` method on that class when you need that class to be comparable to itself (although in theory, there is nothing stopping you from making the class comparable to something other than itself).

Comment: That was implied, there shouldn't by any situation where you would want a new behaviour of compareTo other than the case of a new class that needs it.

Comment: But in your question you wrote: *"a new class that extends comparable having newclass as type parameter must be created ... and the same must be done everytime a new behaviour of the method is needed. Is this correct?"* - you are positing that one should write a new class every time a new behaviour of `compareTo` is needed, which is back to front.

Comment: If want to have a compareTo(newclass o) I have to write that new class first, otherwise the type newclass of the argument I'm passing wouldn't even exist.

Comment: The idea is: in the method body of compareTo in the Comparable interface I can't do something like this: if the type of the argument passed is A behave like this, if is B behave like that and so on... I have to make a new class A that extends Comparable<A> and inside make an override of compareTo that takes an argument of type A

Comment: But why would you want to implement `compareTo(newclass o)` if newclass doesn't even exist?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234069/discussion-between-mizzet-and-kaya3).